# unable to launch the application in tablet resolution while it is launching in small resolution

Tags: android, android-emulator

i am implementing an small android application which is launching properly in small resolution devices and emulators properly.But i am unable to launch the same application in huge resolution(tablet)  emulator.And i am getting below exception.

```
06-06 05:30:56.958: W/ActivityManager(295): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
06-06 05:30:56.958: D/ExchangeService(771): !!!  Email application not found; stopping self
06-06 05:30:57.009: W/ActivityManager(295): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
06-06 05:30:57.102: E/ActivityThread(771): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d1c0b0 that was originally bound here
06-06 05:30:57.102: E/ActivityThread(771): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d1c0b0 that was originally bound here
06-06 05:30:57.102: E/ActivityThread(771):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-06 05:30:57.102: E/ActivityThread(771):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-06 05:30:57.102: E/ActivityThread(771):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-06 05:30:57.102: E/ActivityThread(771):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-06 05:30:57.102: E/ActivityThread(771):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-06 05:30:57.102: E/ActivityThread(771):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-06 05:30:57.102: E/ActivityThread(771):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-06 05:30:57.102: E/ActivityThread(771):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
06-06 05:30:57.102: E/ActivityThread(771):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
06-06 05:30:57.102: E/ActivityThread(771):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-06 05:30:57.102: E/ActivityThread(771):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-06 05:30:57.102: E/ActivityThread(771):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-06 05:30:57.102: E/ActivityThread(771):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-06 05:30:57.102: E/ActivityThread(771):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-06 05:30:57.102: E/ActivityThread(771):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-06 05:30:57.102: E/ActivityThread(771):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-06 05:30:57.123: E/StrictMode(771): null
06-06 05:30:57.123: E/StrictMode(771): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d1c0b0 that was originally bound here
06-06 05:30:57.123: E/StrictMode(771):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-06 05:30:57.123: E/StrictMode(771):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-06 05:30:57.123: E/StrictMode(771):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-06 05:30:57.123: E/StrictMode(771):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-06 05:30:57.123: E/StrictMode(771):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-06 05:30:57.123: E/StrictMode(771):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-06 05:30:57.123: E/StrictMode(771):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-06 05:30:57.123: E/StrictMode(771):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
06-06 05:30:57.123: E/StrictMode(771):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
06-06 05:30:57.123: E/StrictMode(771):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-06 05:30:57.123: E/StrictMode(771):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-06 05:30:57.123: E/StrictMode(771):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-06 05:30:57.123: E/StrictMode(771):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-06 05:30:57.123: E/StrictMode(771):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-06 05:30:57.123: E/StrictMode(771):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-06 05:30:57.123: E/StrictMode(771):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-06 05:30:57.168: W/ActivityManager(295): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@4104c798
06-06 05:30:57.228: E/ActivityThread(771): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d1c478 that was originally bound here
06-06 05:30:57.228: E/ActivityThread(771): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d1c478 that was originally bound here
06-06 05:30:57.228: E/ActivityThread(771):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-06 05:30:57.228: E/ActivityThread(771):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-06 05:30:57.228: E/ActivityThread(771):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-06 05:30:57.228: E/ActivityThread(771):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-06 05:30:57.228: E/ActivityThread(771):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-06 05:30:57.228: E/ActivityThread(771):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-06 05:30:57.228: E/ActivityThread(771):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-06 05:30:57.228: E/ActivityThread(771):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
06-06 05:30:57.228: E/ActivityThread(771):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
06-06 05:30:57.228: E/ActivityThread(771):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
06-06 05:30:57.228: E/ActivityThread(771):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-06 05:30:57.228: E/ActivityThread(771):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-06 05:30:57.228: E/ActivityThread(771):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-06 05:30:57.228: E/ActivityThread(771):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-06 05:30:57.228: E/ActivityThread(771):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-06 05:30:57.228: E/ActivityThread(771):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-06 05:30:57.228: E/ActivityThread(771):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-06 05:30:57.308: E/StrictMode(771): null
06-06 05:30:57.308: E/StrictMode(771): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d1c478 that was originally bound here
06-06 05:30:57.308: E/StrictMode(771):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-06 05:30:57.308: E/StrictMode(771):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-06 05:30:57.308: E/StrictMode(771):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-06 05:30:57.308: E/StrictMode(771):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-06 05:30:57.308: E/StrictMode(771):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-06 05:30:57.308: E/StrictMode(771):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-06 05:30:57.308: E/StrictMode(771):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-06 05:30:57.308: E/StrictMode(771):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
06-06 05:30:57.308: E/StrictMode(771):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
06-06 05:30:57.308: E/StrictMode(771):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
06-06 05:30:57.308: E/StrictMode(771):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-06 05:30:57.308: E/StrictMode(771):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-06 05:30:57.308: E/StrictMode(771):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-06 05:30:57.308: E/StrictMode(771):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-06 05:30:57.308: E/StrictMode(771):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-06 05:30:57.308: E/StrictMode(771):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-06 05:30:57.308: E/StrictMode(771):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Please help me

Comment: Thanks for the down votes.But i need solution also

Comment: Hello, anyone Please help on this event.

Answer (score 0):

add below line in your activity in manifest file:

```
android:configChanges="screenSize|keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Comment: still getting same problem

Answer (score 0):

You are doing something after your service has been stopped.

Add `unbindService(mConnection);` in your `onStop()` method. The code will start working properly.
And I don't think so this is anyway related to screen resolution.

Comment: But it is working for other resolution,And i am not used onStop() for my any Activities

Comment: All are the android versions same?